# Broadcom BCM5720 not working in Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: networking, drivers, dell, broadcom

I need help, I can manage to get the network cards of my Dell T420 (Broadcom BCM5720)

The networks appear as UNCLAIMED.
I manage to connect a wireless usb to get internet and try to solve the issue, but I need to configure the network cards.

I downloaded the QLogic_E3_Manual from dell: https://dl.dell.com/FOLDER06268051M/1/QLogic_E3_Manual_External_End_User_35.07.00.11.zip
And It says that the module for the BCM52XX netword cards are the bnx modules: bnx2, bnx2x, cnic, bnc2i and bnx2fc

I'm loading the bnx modules in the modules.conf

I was looking for the bge modulo but didn't find a way to install it, taking into account this post: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/bge.4freebsd.html. But I'm not sure this module is the one I need.

Any ideas?

Adding the output of some commands:

```
root@emergente:~# uname -a
Linux emergente 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@emergente:~# lshw -C network
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d90a0000-d90affff memory:d90b0000-d90bffff memory:d90c0000-d90cffff memory:dd000000-dd0007ff
  *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d90d0000-d90dffff memory:d90e0000-d90effff memory:d90f0000-d90fffff memory:dd000800-dd000fff
  *-usb:1
       description: Wireless interface
       product: WN7512BEP Wireless LAN adapter
       vendor: Arcadyan
       physical id: 8
       bus info: usb@2:1.8
       logical name: wlxac1826809bac
       version: 1.01
       serial: ac:18:26:80:9b:ac
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=5.4.0-26-generic firmware=0.36 ip=192.168.1.251 link=yes maxpower=450mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11


root@emergente:~#  lspci |grep net
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe

root@emergente:~# ls /sys/class/net
lo  wlxac1826809bac

root@emergente:~# ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 170  bytes 14775 (14.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 170  bytes 14775 (14.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlxac1826809bac: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.251  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::ae18:26ff:fe80:9bac  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ac:18:26:80:9b:ac  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3783  bytes 669361 (669.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 14  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6283  bytes 7173986 (7.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


root@emergente:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ccm                    20480  3
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
dm_multipath           32768  0
scsi_dh_rdac           16384  0
scsi_dh_emc            16384  0
scsi_dh_alua           20480  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      24576  1 intel_rapl_msr
sb_edac                32768  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
ipmi_ssif              36864  0
coretemp               20480  0
rt2800usb              32768  0
rt2x00usb              24576  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib             131072  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              61440  3 rt2800usb,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
kvm_intel             286720  0
mac80211              843776  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_intel
cfg80211              704512  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
intel_cstate           20480  0
dcdbas                 20480  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
intel_rapl_perf        20480  0
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                   106496  1 mei_me
ipmi_si                65536  0
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
ipmi_msghandler       106496  3 ipmi_devintf,ipmi_si,ipmi_ssif
acpi_power_meter       20480  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  5
bnx2fc                 94208  0
libfcoe                73728  1 bnx2fc
libfc                 131072  2 bnx2fc,libfcoe
scsi_transport_fc      61440  2 libfc,bnx2fc
cnic                   61440  1 bnx2fc
uio                    20480  1 cnic
bnx2x                 749568  0
mdio                   16384  1 bnx2x
bnx2                   81920  0
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
btrfs                1249280  0
zstd_compress         167936  1 btrfs
raid10                 57344  0
raid456               155648  0
async_raid6_recov      24576  1 raid456
async_memcpy           20480  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_pq               24576  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_xor              20480  3 async_pq,raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_tx               20480  5 async_pq,async_memcpy,async_xor,raid456,async_raid6_recov
xor                    24576  2 async_xor,btrfs
raid6_pq              114688  4 async_pq,btrfs,raid456,async_raid6_recov
libcrc32c              16384  3 bnx2x,btrfs,raid456
raid1                  45056  0
raid0                  24576  0
multipath              20480  0
linear                 20480  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
mgag200                32768  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
drm_vram_helper        20480  1 mgag200
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 mgag200
ttm                   106496  1 drm_vram_helper
hid_generic            16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
drm_kms_helper        184320  3 mgag200
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
aesni_intel           372736  2
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
usbhid                 57344  0
uas                    28672  0
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
ahci                   40960  0
hid                   131072  2 usbhid,hid_generic
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
usb_storage            77824  1 uas
drm                   491520  5 drm_kms_helper,drm_vram_helper,mgag200,ttm
lpc_ich                24576  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
tg3                   172032  0
megaraid_sas          163840  4
wmi                    32768  0

root@emergente:~# dmesg |grep QLogic
[    7.530596] bnx2x: QLogic 5771x/578xx 10/20-Gigabit Ethernet Driver bnx2x 1.713.36-0 (2014/02/10)
[    7.568020] cnic: QLogic cnicDriver v2.5.22 (July 20, 2015)
[    7.723639] bnx2fc: QLogic FCoE Driver bnx2fc v2.12.10 (October 15, 2015)

root@emergente:~# more /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
bnx2
bnx2x
cnic
bnc2i
bnx2fc



root@emergente:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:165f]
        DeviceName: NIC1
        Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:165f]
        Kernel modules: tg3
01:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:165f]
        DeviceName: NIC2
        Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:165f]
        Kernel modules: tg3

olver@emergente:~$ sudo modprobe tg3
olver@emergente:~$


olver@emergente:~$ dmesg | grep tg3
[    1.417559] tg3.c:v3.137 (May 11, 2014)
[    1.437058] tg3 0000:01:00.0: phy probe failed, err -19
[    1.573417] tg3 0000:01:00.0: VPD access failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update
[    1.639121] tg3 0000:01:00.0: Problem fetching invariants of chip, aborting
[    1.913546] tg3 0000:01:00.1: phy probe failed, err -19
[    2.045464] tg3 0000:01:00.1: VPD access failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update
[    2.045656] tg3 0000:01:00.1: Problem fetching invariants of chip, aborting
```

**UPDATE1:**

```
olver@emergente:~$ sudo modprobe tg3 && dmesg | grep tg3
[sudo] password for olver:
[    1.417559] tg3.c:v3.137 (May 11, 2014)
[    1.437058] tg3 0000:01:00.0: phy probe failed, err -19
[    1.573417] tg3 0000:01:00.0: VPD access failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update
[    1.639121] tg3 0000:01:00.0: Problem fetching invariants of chip, aborting
[    1.913546] tg3 0000:01:00.1: phy probe failed, err -19
[    2.045464] tg3 0000:01:00.1: VPD access failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update
[    2.045656] tg3 0000:01:00.1: Problem fetching invariants of chip, aborting
[259674.731634] tg3.c:v3.137 (May 11, 2014)
[259674.741732] tg3 0000:01:00.0: phy probe failed, err -19
[259674.741929] tg3 0000:01:00.0: Problem fetching invariants of chip, aborting
[259674.753716] tg3 0000:01:00.1: phy probe failed, err -19
[259674.754227] tg3 0000:01:00.1: Problem fetching invariants of chip, aborting
[356350.395520] tg3.c:v3.137 (May 11, 2014)
[356350.409101] tg3 0000:01:00.0: phy probe failed, err -19
[356350.409278] tg3 0000:01:00.0: Problem fetching invariants of chip, aborting
[356350.425109] tg3 0000:01:00.1: phy probe failed, err -19
[356350.425610] tg3 0000:01:00.1: Problem fetching invariants of chip, aborting
```

After the help of @chili555 I know that the tg3 driver is not working and I tried some things in order to get the network cards to work with other module, but It didn't work. I tried this commands:

```
modprobe -r broadcom
modprobe -r tg3
modprobe broadcom
modprobe tg3
```

But it the network cards continue unclaimed and the lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3 continue showing the tg3 modules as the kernel module, even after the modprobe -r tg3.

Now I have the 5.4.0-47-generic kernel, after an upgrade suggested by @kyodake

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe tg3` and also: `dmesg | grep tg3` Firmware??

Comment: I still suggest that you load tg3 and check the log for informative clues: `sudo modprobe tg3 && dmesg | grep tg3` I see no dmesg output above.

Comment: Just added that results some minutes ago.

Comment: Any idea How to tell the kernel to use other driver for this network card?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem.  The appropriate driver, bnx2, is a part of the linux-modules-extra package, which accidentally got removed on my server; bnx2x and tg3 are in linux-modules.  If you have another means of network, try downloading the linux-modules-extra package, or you could boot into a live-usb to add it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped me the first time I ran into the problem: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) - next time I ticked the box for installing Third-party software then the driver was installed and I could connect to the network

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but I have the BCM5720 (not wireless). I tried to follow the main answer, but I didn't found any package for the b57XX network cards. Do you think I should try to install the b43 wireless drivers suggested in that page?

Comment: I do not have any experience with network cards sorry but this guide may help? https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restart-network-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa and this https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_20-04_network_configuration/

Comment: First I need to correct the driver problem to in order to go to that configuration part that is presented in those guides.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ifconfig.8.html

Comment: Yes, the problem is that as the network cards are unclaimed then they don't have a "name" as eth0, eno0, etc. In order to use ifconfig I need the kernel to assign a "name" to the network cards.

Comment: this thread discusses that problem I think https://www.toolbox.com/tech/operating-systems/question/ip-lost-in-reboot-system-022513/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt dist-upgrade

sudo service fwupd start

sudo fwupdmgr refresh

sudo fwupdmgr update
```

Comment: `olver@emergente:~$ sudo fwupdmgr update
No updatable devices`
Did't work. The network cards still are unclaimed.